# Intended usage of \gls for symbols and subscripts

Tags: packages, glossaries

I wonder how to use `\gls` or the package glossaries in general in a proper way in case of symbols and subscripts. For instance without glossaries, I'd just write

```
F_{trac}
```

or in case of in-text usage

```
$F_{trac}$
```

Using glossaries, I defined a symbol for force (`sym:F`) and the subscript for tractive (`sub:trac`) and write

```
\gls{sym:F}[_{\gls{sub:trac}}]
```

or in case of in-text usage

```
$\gls{sym:F}[_{\gls{sub:trac}}]$
```

I can't even spare the `$$` here, which I do for alone standing symbols, which are surrounded by an `\ensuremath{}` in the definition. If two or more subscripts are required I use

```
\gls{sym:F}[_{\gls{sub:trac},\gls{sub:max}}]
```

Also, if one defines an

```
\gls{sym:F_trac}
```

there is no way of adding the `\gls{sub:max}` anymore, is there?

The quite short form

```
v_k
```

becomes

```
\gls{sym:v}[_{\gls{sub:k}}]
```

So my point is:

What is the way the package is intended to be used?

Comment: oh, my, nothing to do with glossaries, but "trac" in the usual math font is quite dreadful.  `\mathit{trac}` is the proper thing if that should be italic, or `\mathrm{trac}` if it's better roman, indicating a short form of a term.

Comment: Is it, @barbarabeeton? What's the difference? Can't see any, at least when it comes to appearance...

Comment: the kerning of the letters meant as math variables (which is what you get by default in math mode) is such that they more clearly appear as individual letters than as a word.  replace "trac" by "effect" and you'll see what i am referring to.

Comment: @barbarabeeton [Interes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)[ting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). Never thought about it.

Comment: Isn't one of the benefits of the `glossaries` package that your label inside `\gls{}` doesn't have to contain a formatted command on it's own?  The name, first, and description can accept a wide variety of macro expansions simplifying the process and generating the proper formatting.  I generate sub and superscripts all the time with the `siunitx` package inside the name entity of a glossary entry and I have never observed a problem with spacing or formatting consistency.

Answer (score 1):

The manual (in section 6.1) states:

> Don’t use any of the \gls-like or \glstext-like commands in the
>   ⟨insert⟩ argument.

(where ⟨insert⟩ refers to the final optional argument) so it's not intended to be used in the form `\gls{sym:v}[_{\gls{sub:k}}]`. The main reason for this is because it causes nested links (if `hyperref` is used). The problem of nested links is mentioned in the `glossaries` FAQ entry [Why shouldn't I use commands like \gls in \section, \chapter, \caption etc?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#whynoglsinsection) but it can be demonstrated using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Targets: \hypertarget{k}{$k$}, \hypertarget{v}{$v$}.

Links: $\hyperlink{v}{v}_{\hyperlink{k}{k}}$.
$\hyperlink{v}{v_{\hyperlink{k}{k}}}$.

No links: $v_k$

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of output]

The first case `$\hyperlink{v}{v}_{\hyperlink{k}{k}}$` is analogous to `\gls{v}_{\gls{k}}`. Here there are two separate hyperlinks, but the spacing between the v and its subscript is slightly wider than the no links version.

The second case `$\hyperlink{v}{v_{\hyperlink{k}{k}}}$` is analogous to `\gls{v}[_{\gls{k}}]`. This has a better spacing between the v and its subscript, but there is now a nested hyperlink. If you click on the k it may take you to the `k` target (`\hypertarget{k}{$k$}`) or it may take you to the `v` target (`\hypertarget{v}{$v$}`), depending on your PDF viewer.

(In either case you will need to use `pdflatex` rather than `latex` for the hyperlinked subscript to appear the correct size.)

Going back to `glossaries`, the usage really depends on how important it is to place each symbol in a hyperlink. If they all need to be hyperlinked, then it's best just to do `\gls{k}_{\gls{v}}`. If you're happy for `k_v` to just hyperlink to the entry for `k` then you can do `$\gls{k}[_{\glsentrytext{v}}]$`, which has better spacing between the k and the v:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{k}{name={k},description={}}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name={v},description={}}

\begin{document}

$\gls{k}_{\gls{v}}$

$\gls{k}[_{\glsentrytext{v}}]$

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Remember that you can define a command if this is too cumbersome to type. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\gsub}[2]{\gls{#1}[_{\glsentrytext{#2}}]}
\newcommand*{\gsubs}[3]{\gls{#1}[_{\glsentrytext{#2},\glsentrytext{#3}}]}
```

Now you can just do `\gsub{v}{k}` or `\gsubs{v}{k}{j}`. This won't add the subscript entries to the glossary, but this can be done by adjusting the definitions:

```
\newcommand*{\gsub}[2]{\gls{#1}[_{\glsentrytext{#2}}]\glsadd{#2}}
\newcommand*{\gsubs}[3]{\gls{#1}[_{\glsentrytext{#2},\glsentrytext{#3}}]\glsadd{#2}\glsadd{#3}}
```